# Store cout output into variable

Tags: c++, string, cout

How can I store the output from cout into a variable of string or character type?

I have written following code but it doesn't work:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std; 

int main(){
    string n;
    n = (cout<<"\nHello world"); 
    cout<<n;    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use a `std::ostringstream` instead of `std::cout`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <sstream>
```

```
std::ostringstream a;
a << "Hello, world!";
std::string b = a.str(); // Or better, `std::move(a).str()`.

std::cout << b;
```

Comment: Thanks its working but Add #include<iostream> Library in it.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have shown you how to capture formatted output using a `std::(o)stringstream` object directly.  But, if for some reason, you really need to capture the output of `std::cout`, then you can temporarily redirect `std::cout` to use a `std::ostringstream`'s buffer, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std; 

int main(){
    ostringstream oss;
    auto cout_buff = cout.rdbuf(oss.rdbuf());
    cout << "\nHello world";
    cout.rdbuf(cout_buff);
    string n = oss.str();
    cout << n;
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/WsK9RH)

Comment: This is a good way to get the data available in the standard streams.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there's a way! But you have to use a different kind of stream:

```
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << "\nHello world";
std::string result = ss.str();
```

Also, in C++20, you can simply use `std::format`:

```
std::string n = std::format("Hello {}! I have {} cats\n", "world", 3);
// n == "Hello world! I have 3 cats\n"
```

Comment: In this case, you should use `std::ostringstream` (output only) instead of `std::stringstream` (input+output), since you don't need to read input from the stream.

Comment: Thanks for your knowledge. Its working

Comment: @AlexG My pleasure! Always happy to help